# PreviewMouseDownEvent of Listbox blocking Command from Button

Tags: c#, wpf, events, listbox, command

In my main view I have a `Listbox` for which I set (among others) the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent` that I use to support drag and drop re-ordering.

```
var style = ListBox.ItemContainerStyle;

style.Setters.Add(new Setter(AllowDropProperty, true));

style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
  new MouseButtonEventHandler(Input_Down)));

private void Input_Down(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is ListBoxItem))
       return;

    var draggedItem = sender as ListBoxItem;

    isDragging = true;
    StartDrag(draggedItem);
}

private void StartDrag(ListBoxItem draggedItem)
{
    draggedItem.IsSelected = true;
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(draggedItem, draggedItem.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);

}
```

In the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` there is a button with an Update command:

```
    <Button Command="{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}" Content="Button"/>
```

However, the command is never triggered when I set the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent`. If I remove the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent` setter, the command works fine. Any ideas on why this is and how I can use both?

Comment: do you set `e.Handled` to `true` in your `Input_Down` method?

Comment: No, I basically just start the drag operation

Comment: can you post code for `Input_Down` method?

Comment: Problem is that `DoDragDrop` interrupts `Click` process. Try if `<Button ... ClickMode="Press"/>` helps but this means that click appears straight away on press and not on release

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I was on a two day break form the code :). Unfortunately it does not change the behavior, the command is still not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **DragDrop.doDragDrop()** operation seems to block all underlying events, meaning that the commands from the buttons that are clicked are not fired.

Since I did not find any clean way of doing this, I decided to go for a *hack*. In the event handler of the ListBox.ItemContainerStyle I check if the original source in the RoutedEventArgs is a Button with an ICommand attached to it. If so, I abort the DragDrop.doDragDrop() procedure:

```
style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent, 
  new MouseButtonEventHandler(Input_Down)));

private void Input_Down(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (EventTriggeredByButtonWithCommand(e))
        return;

    var draggedItem = sender as FrameworkElement;

    if(draggedItem !=null)
        StartDrag(draggedItem);

}
bool EventTriggeredByButtonWithCommand(RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var frameWorkElement = e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;

    if (frameWorkElement == null) 
        return false;

    var button = frameWorkElement.TemplatedParent as Button;

    if (button == null) 
        return false;

    return button.Command != null;
}
```